# How to calculate avg on nested json file. MongoDb

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter-notebook, mongodb-query

I want to calculate the average value of the column 'score2' for each 'show_id', and insert this new value in a new field called 'avg_score'.

this below is my json structure:

```
{'show_id': 's1026',
 'type': 'TV Show',
 'title': 'BoJack Horseman',
 'country': 'United States',
 'IMDB_Rating': 8.7,
 'No_of_Votes': 113345,
 'tweet': [{'_id': '60dae6af60d63d1fa250cb25',
   'text': '@iitstrasha the end of the f***ing world, that 70s show, BoJack Horseman',
   'hashtags': '[]',
   'score1': "{'neg': 0, 'neu': 1, 'pos': 0, 'compound': 0}",
   'score2': 2.0,},
  {'_id': '60dae6b060d63d1fa251d422',
   'text': "@longbothom BoJack Horseman, peaky blinders, The Crown, Orange is the new black, sherlock, Finding 'Ohana",
   'hashtags': '[]',
   'score1': "{'neg': 0, 'neu': 1, 'pos': 0, 'compound': 0}",
   'score2': 0.0},
  {'_id': '60dae6b360d63d1fa258134a',
   'text': 'merlin-is-dead: I’ve been rewatching BoJack Horseman for the first time since it’s finale. I felt like drawing a Di',
   'hashtags': '[]',
   'score1': "{'neg': 0, 'neu': 0.8150000000000001, 'pos': 0.185, 'compound': 0.3612}",
   'score2': 0.185}]}
```

And this is my desired json structure

```
{'show_id': 's1026',
 'type': 'TV Show',
 'title': 'BoJack Horseman',
 'country': 'United States',
 'IMDB_Rating': 8.7,
 'No_of_Votes': 113345,
 'avg_score' : MEAN OF ALL SCORE2,
 'tweet': [{'_id': '60dae6af60d63d1fa250cb25',
   'text': '@iitstrasha the end of the f***ing world, that 70s show, BoJack Horseman',
   'hashtags': '[]',
   'score1': "{'neg': 0, 'neu': 1, 'pos': 0, 'compound': 0}",
   'score2': 2.0},
  {'_id': '60dae6b060d63d1fa251d422',
   'text': "@longbothom BoJack Horseman, peaky blinders, The Crown, Orange is the new black, sherlock, Finding 'Ohana",
   'hashtags': '[]',
   'score1': "{'neg': 0, 'neu': 1, 'pos': 0, 'compound': 0}",
   'score2': 0.0},
  {'_id': '60dae6b360d63d1fa258134a',
   'text': 'merlin-is-dead: I’ve been rewatching BoJack Horseman for the first time since it’s finale. I felt like drawing a Di',
   'hashtags': '[]',
   'score1': "{'neg': 0, 'neu': 0.8150000000000001, 'pos': 0.185, 'compound': 0.3612}",
   'score2': 0.185}]}
```

For each title of series or film there are as many rows as there are tweets. Thanks to all who reply and have a good evening.

i am not familiar with json language, for this reason i would create, non nested field called 'avg_score'. Whit this method i can lead back to pandas dataframe and work on it.

i tried to use this query but it seems not working:

```
results = database.aggregate([
    { '$group': {'_id': '$title', 'vote': { '$sum': "$tweet.score2" }} }
])
[result for result in results]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `$addFields` pipeline stafe instead and perform the required calculation.

```
results = database.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "avg_score": {
        "$avg": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$tweet",
            "in": "$$this.score2"
          }
        },
      }
    }
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P1umZUrbn59)